# How do I remove duplicate values ​in a v-for array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I coded like this to remove duplicate values.

> > vue

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="float: left">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"
      :class="{ active: index1 == currentIndex1 }"
      v-for="(member, index1) in uniqueMemName"
      v-bind:value="member.mem_name"
      :key="index1"
      @click="setActiveMember(member, index1)"
    >
      <strong style="margin-bottom: 5px"> {{member.mem_name}} </strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> > vue (script)

```
  computed: {
    uniqueMemName() {
      return _.uniqBy(this.members, function(m) {
        return m.mem_name;
    });
  }
},
```

I also installed lodash. But I get an error. Which part is wrong?

Please let me know if there is another method other than the one I wrote.

++) error console

[console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uJp0.png)

++) array information:

I have tables A and B. Table A imports only the mem_name column. Table B imports all columns.

Example ->

| a.mem_name | b.col1 | b.col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mem1 | 10 | 20 |
| mem1 | 30 | 40 |
| mem2 | 50 | 60 |

I'm working on making duplicate mem_names into one at this time. Using lodash's unique features.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: And what does the array look like?

Comment: Edited. Could you please confirm?

Comment: How do you import lodash? Try something like this: `import {uniqBy} from 'lodash'` (there is no need to import everything), then instead of `return _.uniqBy(...)`, do this: `return uniqBy(...)`

Comment: Changed based on your comments. But I think my syntax is wrong because the list doesn't appear on the screen at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use lodash just for this, which sounds like the case, I suggest that there may be a better way without it, only using newer vanilla JS:

```js
...
  computed: {
    uniqueMemName() {
      return [...new Set(this.members.map(m => m.mem_name))]
    }
  }
```

Sets are always unique, so mapping and converting to a set and then back to array gives us a unique array.

Comment: Let's try this method too. Thank you :)